# I can't seem to upload css file types in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, file-upload, mime-types

I'm trying to upload a css file user codigniter's upload class.  Here is the controller:

```
public function uploadcssfile() 
{
   $config['upload_path'] = './stylesheets/stores/'.$memberid.'/'; 
   $config['file_name'] = 'main.css';    
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'css';   
   $config['overwrite'] = true;   
   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   if (! $this->upload->do_upload('filefieldname'))
   {
     die($this->upload->display_errors());
   } 
}
```

I just want to upload a file of type css, yet codeigniter always gives this error:

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, try `$config['allowed_types'] = 'css|text/css';`

Comment: sorry had a type, `test/css` should have been `text/css`   obviously ;)

Comment: Just a sanity check; it's not just that the file you are uploading *is* css, it also *has the .css extension*, right?

Comment: `$this->upload->do_upload('filefieldname')` I don't think it expects any parameters, so just `$this->upload->do_upload();` Did you initialise the helper method? e.g. `$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));`

Comment: @ctrahey yes it has the .css extention.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of ci 2.1.2? There were some big fixes with MIME types

Comment: how do i check which version i have?

Comment: just remove this line `$config['allowed_types'] = 'css';` and then try it

Comment: Note: By default the upload routine expects the file to come from a form field called `userfile`, and the form must be a `multipart` type: `<form method="post" action="some_action" enctype="multipart/form-data" />`

Comment: @TheShiftExchange has a point. To find out your version of CI, go to `system/core/CodeIgniter.php`. Around line 36 you'll find the line `define('CI_VERSION', '2.x.x');`

Comment: Are you able to successfully upload some other type of file? I'm not certain that your issue is only with css files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know, this is really weird but it worked for me:

in application/config/mimes.php, line 77

```
'css' => 'text/css',
```

change to:

```
'css' => array('text/css','text/x-c'),
```

To see, if your development environment has its own sense of humour and can add new mime types to any text files (my case), check your mimes like this:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload(-your-form-input-name-) ){
                    print_r($_FILES['-your-form-input-name-']['type']);
                    exit($this->upload->display_errors(). 'File Type: ' . $this->upload->file_type);
                }
```

If an upload fails it will show you what mime type your server is actually getting to deal with.

PS. Now that there is an answer to your question, [go here and help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409546/extending-ci-controller-indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property) :)