# Extending CI_Controller / Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: codeigniter, continuous-integration, php

the CI community seems to have no answer to this (or maybe it is so obvious, that it looks like a noob question?), so I ask here.

I've been seeing this kind of error for a long time now (error messages follow), however I have always used [this "dirty" workaround](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/178540/#851803). Now I do not want to edit the core CI code anymore, and I know there must be a graceful solution to this.

Here is the setup.

In my application/config/routes I have this

```
$route['default_controller'] = "dispatcher";
```

The Dispatcher class in application/controllers/ is defined as this:

```
class Dispatcher extends MY_Controller {

 function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper(array('form','https'));
 }


 function index() {

  # load models
  $this->load->model('site/map');
  $this->load->model('site/langs');
  $this->load->model('site/pages');
  if ( $mapped = $this->map->get_map() ){ // this is the line 21
   $this->langs->set_user_lang( $this->GLO['show_lang_in_url'], $this->GLO['show_lang_at_home'] );
   $red = base_url().$this->GLO['user_lang_label']."/".$mapped;
   redirect($red, "refresh");
   } 

  ...
```

now MY_Controller resides in application/core and is defined as follows:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
  $this->GLO = array();   

  #
  # set defaults:
  #
  $this->GLO['deb'] = '';
  $this->GLO['baseurl'] = base_url();
  ... (more GLO[key] = value ) 
}

 public function __set ($key, $value ) {
  $this->GLO[$key] = $value;
 }
```

Every model I use starts like this (named accordingly):

```
class Map extends CI_Model {

 function __construct(){
  parent::__construct(); 
 }

 function get_map(){
        .....
        return true;
        }
```

Now with CI 2.1.2, PHP 5.3.3, Apache 2 on Debian when trying to load a page, I am getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Indirect
>   modification of overloaded property Langs::$GLO has no effect
>   Filename: site/langs.php Line Number: 82
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: Dispatcher::$map Filename: controllers/dispatcher.php Line
>   Number: 21
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_map() on a non-object in
>   /home/webdev/MC/_WWW/application/controllers/dispatcher.php on line 21

The line 21 is the one marked above in the Map model

```
if ( $mapped = $this->map->get_map() ){
```

the line 82 in the other model looks like this:

```
$this->GLO['langs'][] = $temp;
```

Throughout the code, this GLO array is referenced as $this-GLO[*key*]. It must be read and written from time to time. If I delete the __set function in MY_Controller, I get more of those warnings.

Where is the problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the first error - but these two:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: Dispatcher::$map Filename: controllers/dispatcher.php Line
>   Number: 21
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_map() on a non-object in
>   /home/webdev/MC/_WWW/application/controllers/dispatcher.php on line 21

...look like you havent loaded your model correctly?

change

```
if ( $mapped = $this->map->get_map() ){
```

to

```
$this->load->model('map');
if ( $mapped = $this->map->get_map() ){
```

Comment: There are sub-folders under application/models/, one of them being "site", where the class file resides. As of CI docs, this syntax should actually be correct. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading

Comment: try moving 'map' to the root of 'models' and just see what happens? are you sure you have the files all in lower case?

Comment: Well, it works alright with previous versions of CI and on a couple of live sites. As I said, it all works perfectly if I modify a line in the core CI code. Which is what I want to finally stop doing, hence the question...

Comment: Does the modification solve the two errors regarding 'map'? And does map *actually* work after the modification?

Comment: Yes, the modification I am referencing to – http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/178540/#851803 – works fine and throws no such errors whatsoever.

Comment: ... and no, your proposed modification doesn't work (moving file to /models). Getting the same error.